# using event.stopPropagation()

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with using event.stopPropagation() with following javascript code

```
<li onclick="test();">
  <div>
    <span onclick="test2();">click</span>
 </div> 
</li>
```

While clicking on span it will open a lightbox (jQuery colorbox) with some contents but the problem here is when i clicking on span it is calling `<li>` onclick first, i have tried `event.stopPropagation()` but it doesn't look works for me,can anyone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Why don't you bind the event using jQuery instead of using inline events?!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't bind the events using jQuery.

You need to bind them using jQuery to have access to the properly extended Event object which contains this method for all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/GratT/

```
$('li').click(function(){
   alert('li clicked');
});


$('span').click(function(e){
   alert('span clicked');
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always keep dynamic functions separate from the content. Hence, as every other user will tell you here, bind your event function with the html elements you want them to operate with. Its not hard

```
       jQuery(document).ready(function($)
       {
         $("li").bind("click", text)
         $("span").bind("click", text2);

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 kind of event-capturing methods in modern browsers ("capturing" and "bubbling") and bubble and it depends on the browser you are using. I may be wrong, but as far as i remember mozila-like browser are using "capturing" method while IE is using "bubbling". 
The difference is that "capturing" method starts the event chain from parent to children, meaning that parent event will fire first and the child element will fire last (this happens in your case). Whan you need here is set your event types to Bubble. To do that you need to remove onclick property and replace it with:

```
<li id="lst">
  <div>
    <span id="spn">click</span>
 </div> 
</li>


var element1 = document.getElementById('lst');
var element2 = document.getElementById('spn');

element1.addEventListener('click',doSomething1,false);
element1.addEventListener('click',doSomething2,false);
```

where doSomething1 and doSomething1 are function pointers;
you can also use jQuery event binding, it has it's own event binding functions and by default they are set to bubbling, but you can turn off bubbling and it will use capturing method instead

here is a useful article

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html